# Add datepicker in the multiple input fields in magento admin grid

Tags: magento, dynamic, datepicker, admin, multiple-columns

[image]>

> I have add a new grid in the catalog price rule edit section
>
> and under that there is a dynamic input field there which is done
> through custom renderer.
>
> From my renderer i am returning the input field like as below

```
return "<input type='text' name='validend[$value]'  value='".$getenddate[0]['valid_end_date']."' id = '$value'>";
```

> and it created the input field for each row successfully.
>
> Now i need to add a date-picker to these fields
>
> Can you please suggest me that how can i use the magento default
> datepicjker there in multiple input fields,

Answer (score 1):

ok i am able to do this by magento default caleder libraray , i paas the dynaic id and value for each row like below

```
return "<input type='text' name='validend[$value]'  value='".$getenddate[0]['valid_end_date']."' id = '".$value."_end'>
        <img title='Date selector' id='".$value."_endz`_trig' class='v-middle' alt='' 
        src='adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/grid-cal.gif'>

            <script>// <![CDATA[
            Calendar.setup({
            inputField : '".$value."_end',
            ifFormat : '%m/%e/%Y',
            button : '".$value."_end_trig',
            showsTime: false,
            align : 'Bl',
            singleClick : true
            });
            // ]]></script>
        ";
```